# Asp net mvc Form does not post all fields on submit as it is supposed to post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this form in my asp net mvc application, check right above the form the fields that are posted. The are couple of them missing. Can´t understand why

```
<form id="FormRegistroUsuario" action="/Account/AdminSecurityUserAccountAdd">
   <fieldset>
        <legend><h2 style="color:black;">Cadastro novo Usuário</h2></legend>
        <table id="tblUsuario">
            <tr>
                <td class="smallField">Username:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName,new { @class = "validate[required]" }) </td>
                <td class="smallField" style="padding-left:10px;">Email:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "validate[required,custom[email]]" }) </td>
                <td style="padding-left:10px;">Ativo:</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Active)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallField">Senha:</td>
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "validate[required, minSize[7]]" }) </td>
                <td style="padding-left:10px;">Repetir Senha:</td>
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "validate[required,equals[Password]]" }) </td>
                <td style="font-size:10px; padding-left:10px;">Habilitar Login com Cert. Digital:</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isCertifiedAdd)
                    <div id="certDigitalBlockAdd">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="smallField">Tipo do Certificado:</td>
                                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.certTypeAdd, new SelectList(Model.certTypeComboBox, "id", "type"), "Escolha...", new { @class="smallField" })</td>
                                <td style="display:none;">@Html.Hidden("certTypeAddHidden")</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Identificação:</td>
                                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.identifierAdd, new { @class = "validate[required] smallField" })</td>
                                <td style="display:none;">@Html.Hidden("identifierAddHidden")</td>
                            </tr> 
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="smallField">Pergunta Secreta:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecretQuestion, new { @class = "validate[required]" }) </td>
                <td style="padding-left:10px;">Resposta:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecretQuestionPassword, new { @class = "validate[required, minSize[6]]" }) </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>                                     
        </table>
        <br />
        <div class="scrollTable" style="margin-left:20px;">
            <span class="boxTitle"><table><tr><td>Grupos Disponíveis</td></tr></table></span>
            <!-- Tipos -->
            <div class="scroller">
                <table>
                    <!-- Indices Disponíveis (Exibidos) --> 
                    @{
                    counter = 1;
                    }
                    @foreach (var role in Model.roles)
                    {
                    <tr id="@counter" class="whiteRow setIndex"> 
                        <td class="adminTipoFormRowIndex">@role</td>
                    </tr>
                        counter++;
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scrollTable" style="margin-left:60px;">
            <span class="boxTitle"><table><tr><td>Grupos Atribuidos</td></tr></table></span>
            <!-- Tipos -->
            <div class="scroller scrollerindex">
                <table>
                 @{
                 counter = 1;
                 }
                 @foreach (var role in Model.roles)
                 {
                    string count = counter + "_a";
                    string inputCount = counter + "_i"; 
                    <tr id="@count" class="whiteRow unsetIndex" style="display:none;"> 
                        <td class="adminTipoFormRowIndex">@role</td>
                        <input type="hidden" id="@inputCo**strong text**unt" name="rolesGroup" value="@role" disabled="disabled"/>
                    </tr>
                     counter++;
                 }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
       <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button-link submitAddTipo"/>         
    </fieldset>        
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#FormRegistroUsuario').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        console.log(form.serialize());
    });
```

Fields been posted:

```
UserName=Guilherme
Email=grlongo.ireland%40gmail.com
Active=true
Active=false
Password=%23t1g2p3&
ConfirmPassword=%23t1g2p3&
isCertifiedAdd=true
isCertifiedAdd=false
SecretQuestion=Qual+a+senha%3F&
SecretQuestionPassword=secreta
rolesGroup=Administrador
```

Does not matter if I use @Ajax.beginForm or this approach the result is the same.

- Sent using Ajax.beginForm
- and ajax submit handle
- Created hidden extras hidden fields to check if they would be posted 
  (And no).

Any help you be very appreciated.

Comment: Your hidden fields have no value, maybe that's why they weren't included.

Comment: lol... man, I have not eve thought about that. I am from brazil. Thanks for that. I´ll change now!

Comment: This is why one must use abstractions as a tool, but understand the inner workings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Hidden fields were inside the div that gets `display:none` so the values were not posted. Just moved to the top of my form and it is working now.

Answer (score 2):

When you're looping in an Array, you need to use the same technique in HTML...

for example, in your `Model.roles` collection, you need to do this:

```
@for (int counter = 0; counter <= Model.roles.Count(); counter++)
{
    var role = Model.roles[counter];

    <input type="checkbox" 
           id="roles_@counter" 
           name="roles[@counter]" 
           value="@role" @(role.active ?? "checked='checked'" : "" />
}
```

*code deleted for simplification*

And **remember** that any empty field is never posted...

btw: you do have in your form only one `Active` property, but by submitting it writes two of them... what's your generated HTML?

Comment: It is the standard behavior when using html helpers for checkbox in asp net mvc. Value is always set in the index 0 of the element that has always element[0] and element[1]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I used only the ID attribute without the name.
When I have added the name attribute, the field was submitted.

Before:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" class="form-control" />
```

Fix:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name=txt class="form-control" />
```